# BibTex doesn't create .bbl file (Using Emacs/AUCTEX)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, emacs, auctex

I am having a real issue with compiling `BibTeX` (has previously worked fine).

When I compile `LaTeX`, an `aux` file is created.

Here is my `test.aux`

```
\relax 
\citation{carron2013big}
\bibdata{rhian}
\bibstyle{plain}
```

I then run `BibTeX` on my `test.tex` and receive the message `BibTeX finished successfully. Run LaTeX again to get citations right`

But **no `.bbl` file is generated** which means non of my citations work.

Here is my `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I really like the paper by \cite{carron2013big}. Its nice. 
\bibliography{rhian.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

And my `rhian.bib`

```
@misc{carron2013big,
title = {Compressive Sensing: The Big Picture},
author = {Carron, I.},
year = 2013,
howpublished = {\url{ https://sites.google.com/site/igorcarron2/cs#reconstruction}}
}
```

output from Emacs is:

```
 'Running BibTeX on text with bibtex $s
bibtex: Need exactly one file argument.
Try bibtex --help for more information.'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to run BibTeX on the `.aux` file, not the `.tex` file.  AUCTeX should do this automatically.  Try doing it from the command line first to make sure there are no other problems: `bibtex myfile.aux` (note: the extension is not strictly necessary, but it is wise to test this first given the nature of the problem).

Comment: Also the `'Running BibTeX on text with bibtex $s` seems odd.  Not `%s`?

Comment: Maybe try and take this line out: howpublished = {\url{ https://sites.google.com/site/igorcarron2/cs#reconstruction}} .  However the other suggestions seem more important.

Comment: @jon I used the terminal to run `bibtex myfile.aux` and the `.bbl` file was created and therefore I was able to create my document. I assume that my AUCTeX settings are wrong then? I usually compile by repeatedly using `C-c C-c`

Comment: Yes, I think they are.  (Although the minimal example you gave won't work without loading a package like `url` or `hyperref`. I'd also fix the spurious extra space in the `howpublished` field.)  Have you done anything to your `.emacs` file?  If you have, look to see if there is something like `("BibTeX" "bibtex $s" TeX-run-BibTeX nil t :help "Run BibTeX")`.  Note the `$s`: that should be `%s`.  I can't imagine how that got mixed up unless you copied and pasted from somewhere which had a typo.

Comment: @jon Changing `$s` to `%s` worked and I can now compile correctly in emacs. I changed something in Tex Command List when trying to change the directory for `.bib` files. Thanks @jon. How do I accept an answer?

Comment: Glad it worked.  I made a brief answer so we can get this off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Based on discussion in the comments.)

For whatever reason, a typo seems to have creeped into the settings of the `.emacs` file.  The error

```
'Running BibTeX on text with bibtex $s
```

was the clue.  The normal AUCTeX setting should be something like `bibtex %s` (not `$s`).  Making the appropriate change in your `.emacs` file should do the trick.  Search for something like

```
("BibTeX" "bibtex $s" TeX-run-BibTeX nil t :help "Run BibTeX")
```

and make the appropriate change.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with you, and I fixed by doing so:

1. in preamble

   ```
   \usepackage{cite}
   ```
2. in document

   ```
   \bibliographystyle{unsrt} % choose a display style  
   \bibliography{rihan} % without '.bib', make sure they are in the same path
   ```
3. command C-c TAB helps to invoke the bibtex file, then compile tex file twice

   ```
   C-c C-c
   C-c TAB
   C-c C-c
   C-c C-c
   ```

see [bibtex](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/) and [TeX emacs command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/TeX-Print.html)

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this specific issue several days. I found it at last:
some LaTex compilers doesn't have default defined bibliography style. So user should specify the style be using command

```
\bibliographystyle{STYLE-FILE}

\bibliography{biblioFILE}
```

and replace `STYLE-FILE` with the desired style file with extension `.bst`
for example if you [download the ASME author templates](http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/conf-1.7b.html) you will see that these commands in the TeX file `asme2e.tex`:

```
\bibliographystyle{asmems4}

\bibliography{asme2e}
```

So if you look at the folder you will see the style file: `asmems4.bst` and also bibliography file: `asme2e.bib`.

The reason my compiler doesn't make `.bbl` file because I just mistakenly cleared the style line because they are not written close to each other. So you may do the same mistake of mine! then the poor compiler couldn't make the `.bbl` file! :D I was in time pressure of submitting the paper and I just created the `.bbl` file myself!!! But after the releasing from the stress I found this simple solution!!! All problems have more simpler solution that our complicated brain thinks! This was another important lesson of life today for me.
Enjoy :)